# Append a dot to element every interval

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple 'processing' *dot wait... dot wait.. dot wait..* for when a user submits a form.

I thought this could be accomplished quite easily with something like

```
<h2>Processing</h2>
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  setTimeout($('h2').append('.'), 500);

});
```

However it gets the first dot down, then throws back an error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Where is my logic failing me on this one? What is the unexpected identifier?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should pass a function to `setTimoeut` function you are passing a jQuery object, and it seems what you want is `setInterval` function.

```
var interval = setInterval(function(){
   $('h2').append('.');
}, 500);
```

Then you can clear the interval using `clearInterval` function.

```
clearInterval(interval);
```